# how to get last key in key value pair object

Tags: javascript, key-value

is there an easy way to get the last key in an object of key value pairs, e.g.

```
var valuePair = {
key: value,
key2: value2,
key3: value3
}

var lastKey = getLastKey(valuePair);

console.log(lastKey);
//Prints 'key3'
```

Comment: There's no "last key", because objects have no order. You may want to get keys into an array, sort it by some criteria, and then grab the last property.

Comment: You cannot do that, because there is no defined ordering to the keys in an object. You can get the "last" key that the runtime *thinks* is the last key, but for all intents and purposes it's a random key.

Comment: have you tried a for.. in loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objects are not arrays, so the keys are not ordered by default.  If you apply your own ordering (e.g., sort) then you could determine what's last, but you would have to define the rules of the sort (e.g., ascii-alphabetical).

If order is not important you can do:

```
Object.keys(valuePair).pop()
```